# Probability of choosing a subset of 3 out of 6 with four choices and replacement

Tags: probability

With a sack of six marbles labeled 1 - 6 and four picks from the sack (with replacement after each pick), what is the probability that the set of marbles picked will include the subset `S = {1, 2, 3}`?

My intuition is the following (though this intuition is not backed up by actual knowledge so is very possibly wrong):

```
pick 1 and 2: 1/1 (in both picks there is a 3/6 chance of picking one from the subset. I added them to come up with 1/1)
pick 3:       1/3 (after the first pick there are two left from `S` unpicked)
pick 4:       1/6 (after the second pick there is one left from `S` unpicked)
------------------
total:        1/18
```

For picks 1 and 2 I don't have a reason why I did `2(3/6)` rather than `(3/6)^2` other than "it felt right." Likewise for why I multiplied `1/1`, `1/3`, and `1/6` rather than adding them.

If my answer is correct, could somebody explain why it's correct? And if not could somebody explain the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse the basics. So, I'll try my best to explain the situation from a counting perspective for you to understand easier, although it is longer.

Any *ordered* four picks $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ has probability $\frac{1}{6^4}$. For example, if you pick $(1,1,2,5)$ in that order, since picks are *consecutive* events, and each pick has probability $\frac{1}{6}$, the total probability of picking that particular sequence will be their multiplication $\frac{1}{6^4}$.

There are $6^4$ different such *quadruples*, so the probability adds up to $1$. We need to find how many of these *quadruples* contains the set $S$ you described.

Case 1: No duplicate entry. $(1,2,3,X)$, and $X$ can be $4,5$ or $6$, i.e. three options, and any order of this quadruple will do the job. So, we have $4! \times 3 = 72$ quadruples satisfying the equation.

Case 2: Have duplicate entry. $(1,2,3,X)$, and $X$ is either $1,2$ or $3$. Assume it is $1$, since the situation is symmetric, we can multiply what we've found with $3$. There are $4!/2!=12$ different orderings of $(1,2,3,1)$. Totally, we have $12 \times 3 = 36$ quadruples for this situation.

Totally, we have $108$ quadruples, and the probability is $\frac{108}{6^4}=\frac{3}{36}$